# Is it possible to know which questions I have protected?

Tags: support, search, protected-questions

I have protected a few questions on a Stack Exchange website. Is it possible to know which ones? I don't remember them anymore.

Comment: I can use your account as an example for the query results (I see you have protected three questions on May 29th), but you've hidden your Meta profile, so I'm not sure if you'd want that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no list in your profile, but you can use the [Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com) if you accept that results can be up to one week old (it's refreshed every Sunday morning). [This query](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/1061942/questions-protected-by-a-user) lists all protections a user has made on a certain site (they may be superseded by a later unprotection).